# Second derivative of $D^{\lambda} UD^{2-2\lambda}U^*D^{\lambda}$ wrt to $\lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

Let $A =  D^{\lambda} UD^{2-2\lambda}U^*D^{\lambda}$ where $D$ is diagonal, $U$ is unitary and $0<\lambda <1$. How may we find $\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial \lambda^2}$?

Comment: How do you define $D^{\lambda}$ ? What is $\lambda$ ?

Comment: I just edited the question to include the definition of $\lambda$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a diagonal element $d_{ii}^\lambda$ of $\mathbf{D}^\lambda$ we have

$$\frac{d d_{ii}^\lambda}{d \lambda} = d_{ii}^\lambda\ln{d_{ii}}$$

except when $d_{ii}=0$ then

$$\frac{d d_{ii}^\lambda}{d \lambda} = 0$$

Then

$$\frac{d\mathbf{D}^\lambda}{d \lambda} = \mathbf{D}^\lambda\ln{\mathbf{D}}$$

Similarly

$$\frac{d\mathbf{D}^{2-2\lambda}}{d \lambda} = (-2) \mathbf{D}^{2-2\lambda}\ln{\mathbf{D}}$$

Define $\mathbf{D}_L \equiv \ln{\mathbf{D}}$

Since

$$\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{D}^\lambda \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D}^{2-2\lambda} \mathbf{U}^* \mathbf{D}^\lambda$$
$$\frac{d \mathbf{A}}{d \lambda} =
\mathbf{D}^\lambda \mathbf{D}_L \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D}^{2-2\lambda} \mathbf{U}^* \mathbf{D}^\lambda -
2\mathbf{D}^\lambda \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D}^{2-2\lambda} \mathbf{D}_L \mathbf{U}^* \mathbf{D}^\lambda + \mathbf{D}^\lambda \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D}^{2-2\lambda} \mathbf{U}^* \mathbf{D}^\lambda \mathbf{D}_L $$

Since the diagonal matrices commute we can write this as

$$\frac{d \mathbf{A}}{d \lambda} =
\mathbf{D}_L \mathbf{A} +  \mathbf{A} \mathbf{D}_L -
2\mathbf{D}^\lambda \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D}^{2-2\lambda} \mathbf{D}_L \mathbf{U}^* \mathbf{D}^\lambda $$

Then

$$\frac{d^2 \mathbf{A}}{d \lambda^2} =
\mathbf{D}_L \left[ \mathbf{D}_L \mathbf{A} +  \mathbf{A} \mathbf{D}_L -
2\mathbf{D}^\lambda \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D}^{2-2\lambda} \mathbf{D}_L \mathbf{U}^* \mathbf{D}^\lambda \right] +  \left[ \mathbf{D}_L \mathbf{A} +  \mathbf{A} \mathbf{D}_L -
2\mathbf{D}^\lambda \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D}^{2-2\lambda} \mathbf{D}_L \mathbf{U}^* \mathbf{D}^\lambda \right] \mathbf{D}_L -
2\mathbf{D}^\lambda \mathbf{D}_L \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D}^{2-2\lambda} \mathbf{D}_L \mathbf{U}^* \mathbf{D}^\lambda +
4\mathbf{D}^\lambda \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D}^{2-2\lambda} \mathbf{D}_L^2 \mathbf{U}^* \mathbf{D}^\lambda -
2\mathbf{D}^\lambda \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D}^{2-2\lambda} \mathbf{D}_L \mathbf{U}^* \mathbf{D}^\lambda \mathbf{D}_L $$

Collecting terms

$$\frac{d^2 \mathbf{A}}{d \lambda^2} = \mathbf{D}_L^2 \mathbf{A} + 2\mathbf{D}_L \mathbf{A} \mathbf{D}_L + \mathbf{A} \mathbf{D}_L^2
-4\mathbf{D}_L \mathbf{D}^\lambda \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D}^{2-2\lambda} \mathbf{D}_L \mathbf{U}^* \mathbf{D}^\lambda -
4\mathbf{D}^\lambda \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D}^{2-2\lambda} \mathbf{D}_L \mathbf{U}^* \mathbf{D}^\lambda \mathbf{D}_L +
4\mathbf{D}^\lambda \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D}^{2-2\lambda} \mathbf{D}_L^2 \mathbf{U}^* \mathbf{D}^\lambda $$

Hope that helps